# Using Generics in c# in order to avoid code duplication

Tags: c#, macros, constraints, generics

(Language is c# with VS 2008)

I have the following problem:
There are a number of structs (provided as is from 3rd party) that all implement certain methods with the same signatures.
I would like to wrap these struct with wrapper classes that implement a certain interface so that these classes can be treated in a uniform way.
Example:

```
interface AnInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

struct Struct1
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

class Struct1Wrapper : AnInterface
{
    private Struct1 m_struct;
    public override void DoSomething() // AnInterface implementation
    {
        m_struct.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Note that Struct1 `DoSomething` method is concrete while Struct1Wrapper implements it through an interface for easier handling.

The same goes with Struct2 and so on - the code of StructXWrapper is the same except for Struct1 replaced by StructX

I have tried using generics in order to avoid code duplication:

```
class GenericStructWrapper<AStruct> : AnInterface
{
    private AStruct m_struct;

    public override void DoSomething() // AnInterface implementation
    {
        m_struct.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

But this won't work since the compiler doesn't have a notion about AStruct `DoSomething()` method.

Any other idea how to implement this without duplicating the code of Struct1Wrapper?
Perhaps there is some macro-like feature or some use of reflection?

Thanks,

Ury Jamshy.

Comment: You should be aware that when you reference a valueType as an interface the valueType will be boxed each time.

Answer (score 6):

You can take a `Action<AStruct>` in the class constructor that takes the method.

You can then create instances like `new GenericStructWrapper<Struct1>(s => s.DoSomething())`

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't *safely* support structural typing (except in certain unusual contexts), so there's no way to make this completely safe *without* code-duplication. You either have to go with SLak's technique of asking the *client* to provide a delegate (will probably involve repeating the same lambda expression over and over) or to *assume* that the underlying types will satisfy the contract of containing a `public void DoSomething()` method.

Going with the second option, here's one way using `dynamic` in C# 4:

```
public class StructWrapper: AnInterface
{
    private readonly dynamic m_struct;

    public StructWrapper(object myStruct)
    {
        m_struct = myStruct;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        m_struct.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now, you *could* try to make this class generic, with the underlying-structure type being  the generic-type argument, but that will probably not help you all that much unless you *also* want to perform *structure-specific* operations on the wrapped-type. Here's an example of that, with reflection and delegates (C# 3 compatible):

```
public class StructWrapper<T> : AnInterface where T : struct
{   
    private readonly Action action;

    // deliberately exposed
    public T UnderlyingStruct { get; private set; }

    public StructWrapper(T underlyingStruct)
    {
        UnderlyingStruct = underlyingStruct;
        action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                  (typeof(Action), underlyingStruct, "DoSomething");
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Note that you can mix and match the two techniques mentioned above, e.g. reflection but without generics.

Usage:

```
AnInterface wrapper1 = new StructWrapper(new Struct1());
wrapper1.DoSomething();

StructWrapper<Struct1> wrapper2 = new StructWrapper<Struct1>(new Struct1());
wrapper2.DoSomething();
Struct1 s = wrapper2.UnderlyingStruct; // generics help here
s.SomeOtherMethod();
```

Comment: Note that with VS 2008, `dynamic` is not yet available. You'd need VS2010 or install .NET 4.0 and directly compile that code from the command-line (via the C# compiler `csc.exe`).

Comment: @stakx: I've provided an alternative that is C# 3-compatible, so that will work with VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax for this:

```
class GenericStructWrapper<AStruct> : AnInterface where AStruct : AnInterface
{ 
    private AStruct m_struct; 

    public override void DoSomething() // AnInterface implementation 
    { 
        m_struct.DoSomething(); 
    } 
}
```

This says that AStruct must implement AnInterface

Comment: The types that AStruct represents do not implement AnInterface - and we can't change that because these are structs from a third-party library, as stated in the question.